# spring cloud stream multi api version

Tags: api, spring-cloud-stream

**The problem:**
A single spring cloud stream application,
have to send out the same data via 2 major versions of the same api.

```
spring:
    stream:
      bindings: 
        myApiV1-out-0:
          destination: api/v1/the/topic
        myApiV2-out-0:
          destination: api/v2/the/topic
```

**Question:**
What is the most elegant solution for this problem?

**Idea / what i want to:**
My application should send to a generic binding using the stream bridge.
This binding should consume my internal model and

- convert it to api mode V1 and send out via myApiV1-out-0
- convert it to api mode V2 and send out via myApiV2-out-0

Is this what i have to implement by my own or is there some kind of pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I think using `StreamBridge` is the right pattern when using Spring Cloud Stream for this use case. Here is a pseudo-code:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<String> receive() {

// convert to API mode V1.
streamBridge.send("myApiV1-out-0", conveted-data-v1);

// convert to API mode V2.
streamBridge.send("myApiV2-out-0", conveted-data-v2);

}
```

Comment: You can also have two functions (one for each API) and use [event routing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing) to route to either of those based on incoming API version

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky can you route to both for each incoming event?

Comment: @Mrc0113 good question. . . Made me think why not? More specifically, why have the ability to route to more than one function? Unfortunately we don't provide this capability at the moment, but as you well aware all you need is to raise an issue ;)

Comment: feature request ;) https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/749